# PHP tweaking on a mail form

Tags: php, html, forms

I got some help with an email form, and I feel that I am almost there as the script sends an email but need a few tweaks before I put the form up.  Here is my code right now:

index.html:

```
<div id="main">
    <form method="post" action="mailer.php">
        <div id="text">
            Please enter your email address.
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="q" id="search" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go!" />
    </form>
</div>
```

mailer.php:

```
<?php

$email = addcslashes($_REQUEST['q']) ;
if ($email==FALSE){
    echo "You forgot to enter your email";
}
else

mail( "example@gmail.com", "E-Mail entered",
"E-Mail entered: $email");
header( "Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html" );
?>
```

A few issues I am running into:

The email being sent does not actually include the email entered, the email comes from Apache@ipaddress.ec2.internal and the Body is Email Entered:
which does not include the email string - is there something buggy with the code?

Also, my if statement doesn't seem to work.  Even if I leave the box black, it still assumes a valid email address was sent.

Finally, is there a parameter that sees if the address is in the correct format? ie: includes the @ the . and the domain?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can use `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to test the submitted address. This function returns `false` if it's not valid. Second, `mail()` requires a 4th parameter to assign a return address in your message header. Here's an example:

```
mail(
   'to@address.com',
   'Subject',
   'Message Body',
   'From: from@address.com'
   )
```

Regarding your if/else statement, test `$_POST['q'] == NULL` first, then change `$email = addcslashes($_REQUEST['q']);` to `$email = str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $_POST['q']);` - no real reason to escape characters in this case. Just take em' out.

Edit: This is what your code should look like:

```
$email = str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $_POST['q']);

$isValid = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if ( $_POST['q'] == NULL ) {

    echo "You forgot to enter your email";

} elseif ( $isValid == FALSE ) {

    echo "Please enter a valid email address";

} else {

    mail(
        'example@gmail.com', // Your address that you want the message sent to
        'Subject',
        'Message Body',
        'From: ' . $email // The address collected
    );

    header( "Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html" );

}
```

Does that make a little more sense?

Do note that because of modern spam filters, this method may not make it to every recipient. Creating useful email headers can be a bit of an art-form that takes some practice.

Comment: yes!  One more thing, the from@address.com - is that the address the email is going to?

Comment: No. That's the address that will replace `Apache@ipaddress.ec2.internal` on the from line of the email - The email will go to whatever address gets passed from the form to `$email`.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to write it so the email address they enter foes to a specific address?  like example@gmail.com?  I would want their email input ($email) to send to example@gmail.com - sorry for my confusion

Comment: Everytime someone enters their email address, the email address they enter should always send an email to example@gmail.com

Comment: Awesome!  Many, many thanks!  Yea it seems like every email goes to the spam folder, I guess there is no way around that

Comment: Do some reading (google search) on spam and email headers. Like I said, there's an art to creating good email header data that spam filters leave alone.

Answer (score 1):

To change the "from field", try something like this:

```
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

As far as your if statement, check the $_REQUEST variable first:

```
if (isempty($_REQUEST['q']) { echo "forgot to enter email"; }
```

Finally, here's a link to a method to validate email addresses: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585

Answer (score 0):

Try this for checking if the email is set.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['q'])) ..
```

As far as the "Email Sender". I believe you are looking for the "From" header.. that can be done like this..

```
$header = "From: Your Name <example@gmail.com>"; 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

More details are available at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php